# In base or data.table for R, use a function, evaluated on a column, to select rows?

Tags: r, data.table

Given a data table `DT` with a column `Col1`, select the rows of `DT` where the values `x` in `Col1` satisfy some boolean expression, for example `f(x) == TRUE` or another example `f(x) <= 4`, and then doing more data table operations.

For example, I tried something like

`DT[f(Col1) == TRUE, Col2 := 2]`

which does not work because `f()` acts on values not vectors.  Using `lapply()`, seems to work but it take a long time to run with a very large `DT`.

A workaround would be to create a column and using that to select the rows

`DT[, fvalues := f(Col1)][fvalues == TRUE, Col2 := 2]`

but it would be better not to increase the size of `DT`.

EDIT: Here is an example.

`map1<-data.table(k1=c("A","B","C"), v=c(-1,2,3))`

`map2<-data.table(k2=c("A","B","A","A","C","B"), k3=c("A","B","C","B","C","B"))`

`f <- function(x) map1[k1 == x, v]`

To find the rows in `map2` using the corresponding value in `map1`: these do not work (returning an error about a length mismatch around ==)
`map2[f(k2) == 2, flag1 := TRUE]`

`map2[f(k2) + f(k3) == 2, flag2 := TRUE]`

but using `lapply()` the first one works but it is somehow slower (for a large data table) than adding column to `map2` with the values of `f` and selecting based on that new column

`map2[lapply(k2,f) == 2, flag1 := TRUE]`

and the second one

`map2[lapply(k2,f) + lapply(k3,f) == 2, flag2 := TRUE]`

returns an error (non-numeric argument).

The question would be how to do this most efficiently, particularly without making the data table larger.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem perhaps is when you're adding the parts which are aiming to modify the `data.table` in-place (i.e. your `:=` parts). I don't think you can filter in place, as such filter really requires writing to a new memory location.

This works for filtering, whilst creating a new object:

```r
library(data.table)

f <- function(x) x > 0.5

DT <- data.table(Col1 = runif(10))

DT[f(Col1),]

#>         Col1
#> 1: 0.7916055
#> 2: 0.5391773
#> 3: 0.6855657
#> 4: 0.5250881
#> 5: 0.9089948
#> 6: 0.6639571
```

To do more `data.table` operations on a filtered table, assign to a new object and work with that one:

```r
DT2 <- DT[f(Col1),]
DT2[, Col2 := 2]
```

Perhaps I've misunderstood your problem though - what function are you using? Could you post more code so we can replicate your problem more precisely?

Answer (score 0):

If `f` is a function working only on scalar values, you could  `Vectorize` it:

```
DT[Vectorize(f)(Col1)]
```

Not sure this fully answers your question because `Vectorize` uses `lapply`/`mapply`